# Probability that Arithmetic Mean of selected numbers is $25$

Tags: probability, permutations

Three natural numbers are selected from set of first $100$ natural numbers.what is the probability that their Arithmetic Mean is $25$?

Total selection=$C(100,3)$

Now if $x,y,z$ are selected then we want

$x+y+z=75$ 
So basically we need unequal positive integral solutions of $x+y+z=75$

Now total positive integral solutions will be $C(74,2)$. Two types of cases are to be removed from $C(74,2)$

$(i)$ When all numbers are equal.(Only one such case)

$(ii)$ When two numbers are equal.

I want to know how to count those cases when two numbers are equal?
One thing that I can think of is manually counting by making cases as $x=y=1$ or $x=y=2$ and so on. But is there any other method?

Comment: If you use $C(100,3)$ as the total number of selections, you're implicitly assuming that the three numbers must be distinct.

Comment: You should specify *how* these random numbers are drawn, and according to which probability distribution. To select a random $3$-subset of $[1,100]$ with respect to a uniform distribution is different from selecting a random number (with respect to a uniform distribution)  from $[1,100]$ for three times.

Comment: @Arthur I am assuming that in set any number is present only once.

Comment: Ahh, I just now understood your thinking. Stars and bars, and then excluding all the bad cases? In that case, remember that $C(100,3)$ chooses without caring about order (i.e. choosing $24,25,26$ is counted together with $26,25,24$ and the other four possible orderings as a single case) while $C(74,2)$ cares about ordering.

Comment: @Arthur I was thinking of removing bad cases from $C(74,2)$ and then divide the quantity obtained by $3!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that bad counting manually the number of cases where two of the numbers are equal. For each number from $1$ to $37$ inclusive (but not counting $25$), there is exactly one value that the third number could be given. That gives $36$ different possible values for the pair, and correspondingly $36$ unordered triples.

The pair could be the first two numbers, the first and the third, or the last two. That gives $108$ different ordered triples that sum to $75$ where two, but not three, of the numbers are equal. So, your final probability is
$$
\frac{\binom{74}2-1-108}{3!\cdot\binom{100}3}\approx 0.0027
$$